# Issues on eclipse generated php files uploaded through ftp

Tags: php, ftp, eclipse-pdt

I have uploaded my PHP project created using Eclipse-PDT to the siteground server.
After completing the upload, i tried to run the php pages and it throws an error saying "Expected End of statement".
          Then i logged in to the CPANEL and found that all the line breaks are removed from the script. since i have used "single line comments" in my php script ,its throwing error(next line will also append to the previous line)
          can anybody help to solve this issue? i have a lot of php pages ,so its not possible to remove all single line comments from all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its caused by different file encoding?
Check which format is used in your editor.